# combinatorics - partitions of sets

Tags: combinatorics

The question is this:

In how many partitions of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ into three disjoint sets, $A$, $B$, and $C$,  are there no two consecutive numbers in the set $A$?

thanks!

Comment: Do you consider these *ordered* partitions, so that, for instance, $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{3\}$, $C=\{4\}$ does not qualify, but $A=\{3\}$, $B=\{1,2\}$, $C=\{4\}$ is okay?

Comment: exactly, second exmpale is okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number of ways of selecting $k$ numbers from $1,2,\dots,n$ such that no two are consecutive is

$\displaystyle \binom{n-k+1}{k}$, for instance see my answer here: [Consecutive birthdays probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18268/consecutive-birthdays-probability/18363#18363)

Once you do that, count the number of partitions of the remaining into $B$ and $C$.

Which is given by $2S(n-k,2) + 2$ where $S(a,b)$ are the Stirling numbers of the second kind (for and explanation see the answer linked above).

Now I guess your answer is

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n-k+1}{k} (2S(n-k,2) + 2)$$

(Note: I haven't tried to confirm it, I leave that to you)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Having pulled out $k$ items for $A$, aren't there $2^{(n-k)}$ subsets that you could choose for $B$ so you would have $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n-k+1}{k}2^{(n-k)}$$?  It looks like your answer doesn't allow $B$ or $C$ to be empty and considers swapping $B$ and $C$ to be the same configuration.

Comment: @Ross: $S(n,2) = 2^{n-1} -1$. I mentioned Strirling numbers because it generalizes to more sets :-) See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number_of_the_second_kind#Simple_identities

Comment: @Moron: yes, I had seen that, which is how I figured out the differences between the approaches.  It depends what you want to count.

Comment: @Ross: Multiplying by 2 and adding 2 is supposed to take care of swapping B and C, and empty sets. The formula($2^{n-1}-1$) then gives what you wrote in your comment, so it does seem to match... Am I missing something, or do we agree now?

Comment: @Moron:  we agreed all the time.  And still do

Comment: @Ross: Your first comment about B and C confused me :-)

Comment: @Moron: sorry for that.  I just read it differently, perhaps prompted by Arturo's question to OP.  Depending upon what you want to count, I think we were both right, and I should have said that earlier.